# How to get grouping values in views

Tags: views, entities

I created a views to show all my products, in each product have a field named "Color", so now I want to group all product has same color.
So now how can I get all grouping values,

```
For exam we have 6 results but just only has 2 colors : Red and Blue without Black one.
```

My question is how can I get grouping values in this views (Red, Blue)

```
$view->some_thing->some_how ?
```

I want to put those values in View footer for my personal purpose

My View should displayed like this

```
--- View Content ----
[RED]
Product 1
Produc 2
[Blue]
Product 3
Product 4

--- View footer
[RED] - [BLUE]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add field in your views
2. select display format
3. like if you are select table format select your value like red in grouping field

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add **Color** field into view.
2. Now click on formate setting.
3. Select the **Color** field as a **Grouping field**.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, but do you know how to render grouping values programmatically, something like $view->how_to_grouping_values